# Base multiplier

Tags: python, range, multiplication, radix

Hello I'm having some trouble with my code to multiply a number to any base from 2 to 9. I have looked online but nothing has the answer I'm looking for.  The code I have right now is:

```
def conver(n,b):
for i in range (b):
    x = b**i
```

What I'm wondering is how do I get `b` to get multiplied by all the values of `i`, also I know that I'm supposed to incorporate these pieces of code too, but I am not sure how:

```
n//b + n%b
```

Comment: can someone please answer it would really help

Comment: Could you clarify your question to explain what you wish to do please

Comment: im trying to make a program that takes a number and changes its base between 2 and 9 for example like (14,2) which would output 1110, because it took 14 and converted it to base 2

Comment: So something like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int,%20int)) but in python?

Comment: @Joe So, the input is always in base 10?

Comment: not really because only numbers

Comment: @tonypdmtr yes it will be in base 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version that will work to base 36:

```
def conver(n,b):
  assert 1 < b <= 36,'Invalid base. Must be between 2 and 36'
  if n == 0: return '0'
  ans = ''
  while n > 0:
    ans = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[n%b] + ans
    n //= b
  return ans

NUMBER = 65535
for b in range(2,37):
  print(NUMBER,'in base',b,'is',conver(NUMBER,b))
```

Comment: what are the letters for and how does it do base 36 to if the numbers go up to 9

Comment: For any base up to 36.  Cut down to as many you want your maximum base to be.

Comment: cut down what? also im not really understanding what the letter do

Comment: If you need to convert up to base 16, you need to keep up to letter F as base 16 goes from 0..F

Comment: interesting, is another way you can do it without the digits